# Implement Equals to make either reference equality or key-based equality?

Tags: c#

I would like to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of my EntityBase class to support checking equality based on reference (as by default) or by the entity key (in case the references not matching).
Here is the code:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    protected virtual object Keys { get { return this; } }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (Keys == this) return base.Equals(obj);
        var entity = obj as EntityBase;
        if (entity == null) return false;
        var re = ReferenceEquals(entity, this);
        return re || Equals(entity.Keys, Keys);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (Keys == this) return base.GetHashCode();
        return base.GetHashCode() * 17 + (Keys?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
    }
}
```

Now in the derived class it can be like this:

```
public class Entity : EntityBase {
    protected override object Keys {
        get {
             return SomeKeyProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

So I expect that it should work, but the `BindingSource` I'm using showed that it does not work, like this:

```
//the myEntity here is contained (as reference) in myBindingSource  
var index = myBindingSource.IndexOf(myEntity);
```

The code above gives the correct result if I don't override `Equals` for my `EntityBase` class, but with that overriding, the result will be wrong, looks like it always tries to look for the item based on the `Keys` value. I don't really understand what's wrong here.

When debugging it does not even hit the breakpoint I set in the `Equals` method. The code just runs through the `IndexOf` call like as it's a black box.

Could you explain to me what's wrong here and give me some suggestion about a possible fix (or even let me know if what I want to achieve is possible).

Comment: Reference equality is always using `==`. Key-based equality can simply be implemented using comparison.

Comment: @Oighea what you said is for comparing the objects directly but here I would like to put the logic in the `Equals` override, so that some collection will use that to such as find index

Comment: I don't think that is recommended. By convention, reference equality (which is stronger than just key equality) always uses `==`

Comment: @Oighea explicitly using `==` may be like what you said, but here internally the collection will use `Equals` to implement `IndexOf`, so I'm not so sure why you always mention about `==`, I don't really care about that, just the `Equals` override that is internally used by some collection, but here somehow it's not working as I expect.

Comment: When you get it working, wouldn't  `Order#1 == Custmer#1` return true?

Comment: @HenkHolterman thank you for your comment, I did not test it thoroughly, and yes you're right. I need to add more code to check the actual Type of the 2 objects (not based on the base type), if the Types don't match then the result should be false right away

Comment: And when you have to add more and more checks it's time to rethink the whole thing. Identity and Equality are very fundamental concepts.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes you're right, I feel it's a bit dangerous here. Actually my scenario here may involve 2 entities being loaded by 2 different context, they should be treated as the same one (of course by being loaded their Keys should not be zero/empty).

Comment: That is a very special circumstance that should be treated explicitly, `x1.Key == x2.Key`, not built into the fabric of your Model.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code I posted runs just like what it should. I want that the reference equality should have higher priority, but really when finding an item (like `IndexOf`) in a collection, what comes first will be the one found (if the references does not match then keys will be used).

The reason it did not work as I expect because the 2 ones compared here both have `Keys` equal to `0`. So if key-based equality is used, that case should be considered as `unequal`. I need to add another property to determine which value is considered as null or empty `Keys`. Here is the code working as I expected:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    protected virtual object Keys { get { return this; } }
    protected virtual object EmptyKeys {get { return null;} }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      if (Keys == this) return base.Equals(obj);
      var entity = obj as EntityBase;
      if (entity == null) return false;
      var re = ReferenceEquals(entity, this);
      return re || GetType() == entity.GetType() && Equals(entity.Keys, Keys) && !Equals(Keys, EmptyKeys);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      if (Keys == this) return base.GetHashCode();
      return base.GetHashCode() * 17 + (Keys?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
    }
}
```

In the derived class, we need to override the `EmptyKeys` to indicate which value is considered as empty, NOTE that for numeric key (like `long`, ...) the value for `EmptyKeys` should be of the exact type with `Keys`, otherwise the `Equals` won't work.

```
public class Entity : EntityBase {
   protected override object Keys {
      get {
         return SomeKeyProperty;//suppose this is a long property
      }
   }
   protected override object EmptyKeys {
      get {
         return 0L;//here 0 value should also be a long value.
      }
   }
}
```

After that adjusting, the code works expectedly.

Comment: "that case should be considered as unequal" is an indication that this whole idea is highly suspect. Do you really have a frequent use-case for this?

Comment: @HenkHolterman actually it's not very frequent, I just have a list of objects including newly added ones (which surely have all their Keys being empty/null/zero).

Comment: And can newly added entitues ever be equal to something else?  I don't see an argument that goes beyond reference quality yet.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think in that case the equality should depend on their `Keys`, the reference almost does not matter here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman another case for key-based equality makes sense here is when using a wrapper class. That class just wraps around an entity (and expose a bit more info via additional props). The reference equality should still work for them while the key-based equality should be important to implement.